# Zero Volt-Seconds Assumption in SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, converter, analysis

What is the logic behind using the “zero volt-seconds” assumption for the analysis of converters and what are the limitations of analysis based on this assumption?

Comment: Context is something you should consider.

Comment: sorry ill spell it out so its clearer, What is the meaning of zero volt-seconds. And how is this significant when perforing circuit analysis on switch mode power supplies. Unsure what more context i can add

Comment: Zero volt-seconds is not sensible in the context you state nor any other I can think of. Try harder.

Comment: The average voltage across an inductor over time must be zero in order for an SMPS producing a constant steady state current., I think is what he's getting at? I don't think that's an assumption though, it's just a physical necessity. Volt-seconds, I think is a reference to the V(t)dt term in a relevant integral. I think the "logic" behind it is related to conservation of energy and all that jazz.

Answer (score 3):

The zero volt-second assumption can be used to simplify analysis of a circuit with inductors when it is in **steady-state**, by considering constant averages over a period instead of time-varying quantities. The method is limited to steady-state analysis, i.e. it can not be used to analyse transient effects or circuit properties in the presence of transients. This is a general analysis method and does not only apply to switch-mode power supplies.

Steady-state means that the voltage and current waveforms for the circuit are repeating with a time period \$T\$, defined as
$$
    v(t + T) = v(t) \qquad \text{and} \qquad i(t + T) = i(t) \, .
$$
The period \$T\$ is typically the switching frequency when using a force commutated device (transistor), or the source frequency when using a naturally commutated device (diode).

Recall the inductor equation
$$
    v_L = L \frac{\mathrm{d} i}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
and rearrange it as
$$
    \frac{1}{L} v_L \mathrm{d} t = \mathrm{d} i \, .
$$
Integrating both sides from the time \$t_1\$ to \$t_1 + T\$ yields, for steady-state:
$$
    \frac{1}{L} \int_{t_1}^{t_1 + T} v_L \mathrm{d} t = \int_{i(t_1)}^{i(t_1 + T)} \mathrm{d} i = i(t_1 + T) - i(t_1) = 0
$$
In steady-state the above integral has to be equal to zero, or we would not be in steady-state by definition.

The above integral implies that there must be at least one time instance \$t_m\$ when the polarity of the voltage changes
$$
    \int_{t_1}^{t_1 + T} v_L \mathrm{d} t = \int_{t_1}^{t_1 + t_m} v_L \mathrm{d} t_1 + \int_{t_1 + t_m}^{t_1 + T} v_L \mathrm{d} t = A + B = 0
$$
such that the two areas \$A\$ and \$B\$ sum to zero. The areas will have the units volt-second. The areas are (proportional to) the time-averages of the inductor voltage and will remain constant in steady-state. See the diagram I created below:

[image: zero volt-second]

A similar argument can be made for capacitors in steady-state.